# Why doesn't my state update in a way that seems sense?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add 1 to `countMoves` any time this setState happens. But why doesn't this code work?

```
    const initialState = {
        show: {isShow: false, indexes: [], winnerId: []},
        countMoves: 0,
        stars: [1, 1, 1],
        time: {minute: 0, second: 0}
    }
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
    const handleClick = (index) => {
        if(state.show.indexes.length === 1){
            setState({...state, countMoves: state.countMoves + 1})
        }
.
.
.
```

However, when I change setState to this:

```
setState({...state, countMoves: state.countMoves++ })
```

or

```
setState({...state, countMoves: state.countMoves += 1 })
```

This works! I think the first code is correct.

Comment: How do you know the first code snippet isn't working as expected? What did you do to debug it?

Comment: `state.countMoves + 1` is not an assignment, you're just calculating a new value for the `countMoves` property. `state.countMoves++` and `state.countMoves += 1` are examples for implicit and explicit assignments of a value to `state.countMoves`, then that new value is also assigned to the `countMoves` property.

Comment: @SeanAnglim In the output, when I click It is not added to 'countMoves' value. But if I use `setState({...state, countMoves: state.countMoves++ })` it's added. It fixed by this, but I want to know why doesn't the first code work.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi Try this to visualize when values are assigned and when they're just used for computation of a different value: `foo = 1; console.log(foo + 1, foo++, ++foo, foo += 1, foo);`. Also note the difference between `++foo` and `foo++`.

Comment: @oriberu You're not correct - while `state.countMoves + 1` is indeed not an assignment, `countMoves: state.countMoves + 1` is and is perfectly valid code.

Comment: @SeanAnglim That's what I'm saying (doesn't help that both properties are named the same). In `foo: state.bar + 1` foo is assigned to, but state.bar is not - so the latter's value is not updated.

Comment: @oriberu Thank you. But it still no sense to me. I think it should work as if it was for example: `countMoves: 2`. It should first calculate `state.countMoves + 1` that here gets `1`, then it's assigned to `countMoves`. Isn't it?

Comment: @SeanAnglim Maybe I read your question wrong. I'm saying the value of `state.countMoves` will not change when you don't assign to it, so your result in that instance will always be 1; I thought you expected `state.countMoves` to grow as well.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi Are you able to create a [mre] so we can see this behavior for ourselves (you can make a snippet using [How do I create a React Stack Snippet with JSX support?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537))? Your first code block should be working, just keep in mind that `state.countMoves` will only be updated when the rerender occurs, it won't be updated before that.

Comment: @oriberu Yes, I want to grow it after any click. Is it for that in `countMoves: state.countMoves + 1`, first `state.countMoves`(that is 0) is assigned to `countMoves` and then `1` is added to it? So it always updates to the same `0`.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi Sorry, I didn't realize that you're updating the very same object. No, the calculation is done first and then the assignment happens. I'm with Nick Parsons in that it's probably a matter of when and how you're looking at the new object.

Comment: @NickParsons It's my code and the problem is in `gamaPage.js`. It also is output. https://github.com/arman-ebrahimi/card-memory-game you can see `Moves` doesn't update after the second click.https://friendly-cascaron-e0e8b3.netlify.app/

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi You have other calls to `setState()` further down in your function call, so those overwrite what you're trying to set in the first if-statement (the calls don't "accumulate" together, the last one just takes precedence). FYI - generally, it's preferred that you make a minimal example of your issue (as part of the debugging process before posting), and then share that instead of your entire project if your still stuck :)

Comment: @NickParsons, Excuse me, I removed the first if statement and put changing to `countMoves` inside the other two ifs. It works fine. But according to what you said, updating to `stars` property should be overwritten, too. But it works correctly! why?

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi sorry I forgot to reply. Are you able to share how you changed your code?

Comment: @NickParsons, I thought setState(about stars) should be rewrite by next setState. So I changed it so that I put updating to stars inside the next setState(not concerned about rewriting). But I have another problem now. When I click the game reload button(handleReload function), I update the state to 'initialState' so I expect stars to be updated too. But if you try it on, you'll see stars remain in before state. Why? Code: https://github.com/arman-ebrahimi/card-memory-game  output: https://friendly-cascaron-e0e8b3.netlify.app/

Comment: It fixes by ` const handleReload = () => {
        setState({...initialState, stars: [1,1,1]});
    }` but it's not logical because `stars` in initialState is [1,1,1] by default

Comment: It's because `let newStars = state.stars;` doesn't create a copy of `state.stars`, if instead just makes `newStars` point to the same array in memory that `stat.starts` does. That means that when you update `newStars` you're updating your `state` object (which then updates your `initialState` object). `let newStars = [...state.stars];` is one way to make a copy.

Answer (score 0):

It is working perfectly fine for me. I think previously if condition in handleClick is not passed. So it did not enter if block and update state. Now I added an element in indexes array . It is working as expected and updating state.

```
  const initialState = {
    show: {isShow: false, indexes: [1], winnerId: []},
    countMoves: 0,
    stars: [1, 1, 1],
    time: {minute: 0, second: 0}
}
const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
const handleClick = (index) => {
  console.log(state)//just to see value
    if(state.show.indexes.length === 1){
        setState({...state, countMoves:state.countMoves+1})
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand my problem. Because it should update countMoves after the second click. So indexes should be empty first.